# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion Error

Tags: php

Been experiencing this error for a little while and can't find any conclusive answers on fixing it. I have tried removing quotes from `$key` in line 59 but to no avail.

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_POST['$key'] =  trim(addslashes($value));
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET)) {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            $_GET[$key] = trim(addslashes($value));
        }
    }   
}
```

**LINE 59**

```
$_POST['$key'] =  trim(addslashes($value));
```

**Error On Screen**

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\library\config.php on
>   line 59

Comment: not $_POST['key']?? , anyways your post value is an array. That's why you're getting error

Comment: @Sudhir so just rename `$value` to something else?

Comment: It looks like a very bad practice. If you need to escape user inputs (Assuming you're using MySQL), please read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: This is all my fault (see this change in the PHP core: http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=318288), but for a good reason: in october 2011 I stumbled upon a very hard-to-debug issue that was caused by a silent conversion of an array as a string. Prior to PHP 5.4, an array being used as a string was silently converted as "Array". Since there was no way of being alerted by such silent conversion and the fact that this is a destructive operation that just doesn't make sense, I decided to fix this by emitting a notice since this should never happen in correctly written program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it is array before you assign it

```
$_POST[$key] =  !is_array($value) ? trim(addslashes($value)) : '';
   //  ^   Remove the quotes here                          //  ^ Do something 
                                                           //  Instead of 
                                                           //  Using empty
```

Comment: Just using that seems to get rid of the error. What would you suggest should be done instead of leaving it empty?

Comment: @Beardy, Create an handler both cases one being array and one being string.

Comment: I have used this `$_POST[$key] =  !is_array($value) ? trim(addslashes($value)) : $value;`

Comment: @Beardy, That will return array in case in it array. If that fits your need then should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this code `$_POST[$key] =  $value;` instead of using this `$_POST['$key'] =  trim(addslashes($value));`

or make a check if the value is in array or not

Comment: And how about the quotes around `$key`, eh?

Comment: It should be `$_POST[$key] = $value;` 
I have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it !

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) the function addslashes() takes a String type as parameter. Check what type $value is. If it is an array itself then addslashes() may be throwing the error.

PS:
You should use $_POST[$key] rather than $_POST['$key'] if you want to use the value of $key as the index of the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
foreach ($_POST as &$value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ?
        array_map(function($x) { return trim(addslashes($x)); } :
        trim(addslashes($value));
}
```

However, this could still fail if any of your parameters are multi-dimensional arrays. As mentioned in the comments, the right solution is to use prepared queries with parameters, rather than interpolating strings into SQL.